# OpenGL Error with Executable .JAR (Architecture Word Mismatch?)

Tags: java, maven, opengl, executable-jar, jogl

I've created an OpenGL-based application using Java, [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) and Maven. I'm using [Arch Linux for ARM on a 32-bit machine](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/rockchip/asus-chromebook-flip-c100p). When I build the project from within my development environment, the application loads and executes successfully.

When I use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-2.6/examples/index.html) to generate a JAR which houses both my compiled application code and all of it's dependencies, the executable JAR terminates before it's able to establish an OpenGL context, with an error I've never seen before:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln5003285820939498405/jln7050454496148437271/libgluegen-rt.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln5003285820939498405/jln7050454496148437271/libgluegen-rt.so: /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln5003285820939498405/jln7050454496148437271/libgluegen-rt.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:575)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:95)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:459)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:146)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.<clinit>(AnimatorBase.java:112)
    at com.app.main(Main.java:123)
```

Do you have any idea what could be the issue? One thing that might be worth mentioning is that I use emulated graphics on this machine, so I depend upon software rasterization.

Comment: It doesn't work in your emulator but it should work on a real ARM or 32-bit x86 machine without emulation. When you use an emulator, GlueGen fails to detect which architecture it should use and load the wrong native libraries. Please explain what you mean by "emulated graphics". Please can you check whether your "executable" JAR contains all native libraries and follows the native layout: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Usage Have you looked at our instructions for this Maven plugin? http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Maven_Assembly_Plugin